# "Bcrypt hashing not supported" error on Laravel 4 on production server with PHP 5.4 & Mcrypt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

I get this error during registration because the passwords are hashed.

I checked, and we are running PHP 5.4.something, and when going through EasyApache on cPanel I also verified that Mcrypt is installed.  What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: There are different configurations for web server and command line. Verify mcrypt is installed and configured for each.

Answer (score 0):

Do a 'phpinfo();' and make sure you have >=5.3.7 and mcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Which environment are you using ? I had a problem with mcrypt on Ubuntu for Laravel until I didn't run
   `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
And ofcourse I had  to enable mcrypt extension in php.ini file.